# How can I install Magisk alongside LineageOS on my S10?

Tags: samsung, rooting, lineageos, odin, magisk

I have an S10, which was not bound to any carriers. I managed to install LineageOS and GApps following the steps from LineageOS' [official site for my model](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/beyond1lte/install) and everything seems to work perfectly. Before installing LineageOS, my phone had the stock Samsung Android 12 installed and, looking at the install instructions over at [Magisk's official website](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#samsung-system-as-root), it seems like I have to perform a particular type of installation to be able to install Magisk.

What I am wondering about is:

1. Do I *have to* use Odin? I am a Linux user and over at the website it states that Odin *only* runs on Windows.
2. Watching videos online, none of the video tutorials seemed to use a Samsung + LineageOS when installing Magisk; they installed Magisk + stock Samsung Android, which brings the question if I need to download and install the official firmware from the Samsung servers or can I just get away with flashing Magisk directly on the device?

Comment: Yes Odis only runs on Windows but there is Heimdall the open-source cross-platform version that is more or less a replacement for Odin. Usually for installing Magisk you need the boot image that is modified by Magisk and then you can flash it. As you have LinegeOS running getting the boot image should be that hard.

Comment: @Robert Oh, okay. Heimdall was what I used to flash LineagOS and GApps onto the device in the first place. So I can basically just follow the steps in the instructions and substitute them with the relevant ones in Heimdall?

Comment: As far as I know, yes (but I don't know exactly what differences between Heimdal and Odin exist). From my understanding Heimdall is the "Linux version of Odin" (from a user perspective).